Metadata in PDFs from HTML
I need to carry some metadata – which could amount to just an ID – from the source HTML, through to the PDF using WeasyPrint, eventually ending up somehow addressable in the HTML rendered by pdf.js (more specifically, react-pdf).
So, for example, if I have this element in my source HTML:
<p class="x00-chapter-title---toc-level" id="my-id">Contents</p>

Using qpdf, I was able to generate a text-readable version of the generated PDF, and happily found this:
<<
  /Names <<
    /Dests <<
      /Names [
        (my-id)
        [
          25 0 R
          /XYZ
          67.25
          810.889736
          0
        ]
      ]
    >>
  >>
>>

...which gives me hope!
But now I am not sure how to use pdf.js to access these details, or even tell me what they mean. Presumably coordinates on the page.
How do I do this?

So I got it with this, gives me all I need:
  const page = await pdf.getPage(pageNum);
  const pageRef = page.ref; // This contains the object reference for the page
  const objectNumber = pageRef.num;
  const generationNumber = pageRef.gen;

  // Get all named destinations
  const destinations = await pdf.getDestinations();


What you have shown is a named destination. This can be, for example, the target of a link annotation. If your document has a table of contents, this might be the place clicking on the table of contents takes you. The destination mapped to the name "my id" is [25 0 R /XYZ 67.25 810.889736 0]. This is a link to the page with object number 25, with left coordinate 67.25, top coordinate 810.89736 and "zoom" 0 (0 = null = don't change the zoom when this destination is clicked).
To extract this info, which is what I assume you want to do you would need to first read the document's page tree (/Pages) to map object numbers to page numbers 1,2...
You would then have a (page number, x, y) triple for the tag "my-id" in your document, which I assume is what you want.
